# postgresql pgadmin keep loading forever

Tags: windows-10, pgadmin-4

I have tried to install postgresql+ pgadmin multiple times. My environment is Window 10 and the postgresql version is 10.15 (postgresql-10.15-1-windows-x64.exe). The installation completed but when I run pgadmin, it just keep loading as attached.

[image]

And when I run powershell `get-process`, this is what I get:
[image]

I tried to uninstall it and kill at the process and re-install again, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Just installed pgAdmin and have the same issue. Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: No, I haven't solve it still.

Comment: I just went with 4.20 and it's bringing up the UI. 

https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.20/windows/

Comment: Downgrading to 4.26 helped in my case. On another pc 4.28 is working fine (but no postgres installed there).

Comment: Works for me: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840826/pgadmin-4-v4-28-keeps-loading)

Comment: I realise it's due to version compatibility

Answer (score 11):

I've had the same problem. The link here has the solution: https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#12

The problem is that the value of the ContentType object in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT / .js is set to text / plain. If you follow the steps below, your problem will be resolved.

1. Open the Registry Editor (Run -> regedit)
2. Find `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js` and change the **ContentType** value as **text/javascript**
3. **Restart** the pgAdmin server

If you do not want to use it through the browser, I recommend you to try the desktop version as well.
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: Hi, I can't find the ContentType in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js

Comment: Hi, between HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT to .js have backslash

Answer (score 5):

Me faced the same problem as well . The link here has the solution: https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#12

The problem is that the value of the ContentType object in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT / .js is set to text / plain. If you follow the steps below, your problem will be resolved.

Open the Registry Editor (Run -> regedit)

1.Find HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js

2.Change the ContentType value as text/javascript

3.Restart the pgAdmin  by shutting down the previous server

It will surely work.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble finding the key and change the ContentType to text/javascript

Actually the full path in regedit is **Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js**

Comment: Welcome to SO. This doesn't answer the question

Comment: I also can't find ContentType there

Answer (score 1):

To anyone that couldn't find the ContentType in **Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js** and there is only the (Default), just create a new one.

"New -> String Value"

I had to set the name as Content Type because ContentType didn't made any difference.