# Cant access PGadmin web url Running on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, pgadmin-4, rancher

I have configured pgadmin to run on kubernetes.  My issue is when I use ingress i get the following:
[pgadmin web url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIkTI.png)
When I do inspect i get:[Mime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYOK6.png)

Note the issue is not related to:  [Pgadmin is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829748/pgadmin-is-not-loading)

as its gets defined in init.py file
[init.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYOK6.png)

So what is confusing is that if I do kubectl port forward (bypass ingress) it works fine
[localhost:8282](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYiFb.png)

Comment: What version of pgadmin are you using?

Comment: Also, your `init.py` screenshot is the same as the "Mime error" one. Did you mean to include a different one?

Comment: Sorry think i added the wrong info in init.py.                                                                # Explicitly set the mime-types so that a corrupted windows registry will not
# affect pgAdmin 4 to be load properly. This will avoid the issues that may
# occur due to security fix of X_CONTENT_TYPE_OPTIONS = "nosniff".
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type('application/javascript', '.js')
mimetypes.add_type('text/css', '.css')                                                                      This is what the script says. I have tried pgadmin4-6.8 and pgadmin4-6.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some troubleshooting I found.

Took the image back to http. Made the ingress https and add annotation to call backend http.