# pgadmin 4 v7.4 keeps loading but does not open

Tags: pgadmin-4

I installed pgadmin 4 v7.4 and opened as administrator and it keeps loading but does not open (see screnshot below).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yw6m.png)

I saw several similar posts for earlier versions (i.e., [pgadmin 4 v4.28 keeps loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840826/pgadmin-4-v4-28-keeps-loading)). I also tried editing HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT to change the value data field to text/javascript per [Pgadmin is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829748/pgadmin-is-not-loading). None of these have worked.

I am running Windows 11. Any advice? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: I was told that you'd need to downgrade to pgAdmin 7.3 until this known issue is fixed. Personally, I downgraded to 7.0 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

install version 7.5, it´s work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).